# Is there any conceptual difference between these kinds of sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, word-order

> Read out the sentence.
>
> Read the sentence out.
>
> Read the sentence aloud.
>
> Read aloud the sentence.
>
> Bring the boy out.
>
> Bring out the boy.

What exactly is the difference between these kinds of constructions?

Comment: All would be understood, but some are more idiomatic. **read out** and **bring out** are phrasal verbs, commonly used idioms and so seem natural  to me. Whereas **Read aloud** is not a familiar phrasal verb and so **read aloud the sentence** seems odd to me.

Answer (score 1):

In:

> Bring the boy out.
>   Bring out the boy.

either is fine since *out* indicates a direction/location.

In the others, not the first two, because there is no location/direction. Using *aloud* is OK but I would prefer:

> Read the sentence **out loud**.

Answer (score 0):

Tha actions verbs are transitive, which have direct objects and intransitive, which have an indirect object.

> Rahul smoothed the **bedspread** out.

The bold part is an indirect object, and the actions verb is intransitive.

Smoothed=transtive

> Leslie didn't have any money for a sandwich, so Smitty purchased **her** it.

The bold part= indirect object.

It= direct object.

Purchased= transitive.

Transitive verbs necessarily have a verb complement.